# Which user is used windows authentication for connecting MSSQL in Windows task scheduler

Tags: talend, windows-task-scheduler

Windows task scheduler has one author(it is a login user account) and one user account (This account is used when this task is running). Which user is used for windows authentication If this task scheduler used to run the Talend Jobs and these jobs used connecting to remote MSSQL using windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When talend jobs are scheduled through task scheduler, it will use run user account for connecting to SQL Server. (Not the author account)